# Trait bound for move-closures?

Tags: rust, closures, traits, lifetime, borrow-checker

Is there a way to distinguish `move` closures from non-`move` closures using a trait bound in Rust?

For context, I'm using boxed closures in my program (`Box + dyn Fn` trait), so I need to worry about lifetimes since IIUC these closures may reference the stack.

I was wondering whether I could maybe restrict to boxed `move`-closures only so that (hopefully) I could avoid dealing with lifetimes, since these quickly get messy in this case.

Or is there some other better, more idiomatic way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Boxed trait objects already get a default `'static` bound, source: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes

Comment: To be more explicit, the trait bound `Fn(...) + 'static` refers to a closure without any non-static external references. You don't care about whether they were created using the `move` keyword, or whether they avoided having external references by any other means. For `Box<dyn Fn(...)>` the static lifetime bound is implicit, as @pretzelhammer pointed out. If you actually want to allow non-static lifetimes, you need to explicitly add a `+ 'a` bound.

Comment: @SvenMarnach thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to distinguish move closures from non-move closures using a trait bound in Rust?

"Moving" is a red-herring here. You can borrow a variable by reference in a closure *or* you can **move** a reference into a closure and they're equivalently the same. Example:

```rust
fn takes_closure<'a>(_closure: &'a dyn Fn() -> &'a i32) {}

fn main() {
    let value = 123;
    let value_ref = &value;
    
    // captures value by borrowing it by reference
    takes_closure(&|| &value);
    
    // captures value_ref by moving it
    takes_closure(& move || value_ref);
    
    // what's the difference between the above 2 cases?
    // answer: there isn't any
}
```

> I'm using boxed closures in my program so I need to worry about lifetimes since IIUC these closures may reference the stack.

Nope, by default boxed closures get an implicit `'static` bound. Unless you explicitly set your own lifetime bound you can't borrow stack variables in a boxed closure.

[From *Default trait object lifetimes* in The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes):

> If the trait has no lifetime bounds, then the lifetime is inferred in expressions and is `'static` outside of expressions.

For example, just this function signature alone guarantees the returned closure won't capture any non-`'static` external references or variables:

```rust
fn returns_boxed_closure() -> Box<dyn Fn()>;
// full desugared return type: Box<dyn Fn() + 'static>
```

Like mentioned above, if you want a boxed closure to not be bounded by a `'static` lifetime you have to explicitly annotate it otherwise. Here's an example:

```rust
fn returns_boxed_closure<'a, T>(reference: &'a T) -> Box<dyn Fn() + 'a> {
    Box::new(move || drop(reference))
}
```

The example above is particularly good because it shows *even if* you use the **move** keyword you can still use it to create a boxed closure with a non-`'static` lifetime.

Anyway, in a nutshell: you don't have to do anything special, boxed closures get an implicit `'static` bound by default and work like you want them to, i.e. you don't have to worry about lifetimes.